# Stack is part of the heap or is it separate memory

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I was looking at the documentation

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/JRSDK/garbage_collect.htm

Also found a picture with a memory structure on baeldung

[image]

I learned from the documentation that:

> Each Java Virtual Machine thread has a private Java Virtual Machine stack, created at the same time as the thread

But I cannot understand:
**Is the Stack part of the heap or is it separate memory?**

Comment: The documentation says that already: "Each Java Virtual Machine thread has a _private_ Java Virtual Machine stack" and "the Java Virtual Machine has a heap that is _shared_ among all Java Virtual Machine threads" - so since thread stacks are private and heap is shared (public) they are separate things. Additionally, the documention lists them as separate memory areas already like the method area etc.

Comment: @Thomas I think that such a conclusion cannot be made on the basis of this phrase "*the Java Virtual Machine has a heap that is shared among all Java Virtual Machine threads*"

Since the stack can be part of the heap that is not shared(public).

Comment: If you read the documentation you'll see that heap and thread stacks serve different purposes and visibilities and thus it wouldn't make sense for the thread stacks to be part of the heap. JVMs _might_ make different choices but the heap is more where objects are allocated while the stack just holds primitives and references. They are related but don't overlap. All the documentation you linked also treats them separately and although they might not explicitly state that stack is not a part of heap none would state otherwise as well.

Comment: Note in the diagram you posted, some things are pointers allocated on the stack that point to objects allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the Stack part of the heap or is it separate memory?

The JVM specification does not say.  So in theory it would be possible to implement a JVM where thread stacks are in the heap or in separate (non-heap) memory.

In practice, all JVMs based on the mainstream Sun, Oracle and OpenJDK codebases use separate (non-heap) memory for thread stacks.  One reason is that it simplifies the JVM's memory management if stacks cannot be relocated by the garbage collector.

But the flipside is that it makes no difference<sup>1</sup> to Java programs which approach a particular Java implementation has taken.

---

<sup>1 - Apart from questions like "do I need to increase the heap size to run more threads ...".</sup>